# asp.net mvc 4 (Razor) partial page with layout - Massive Confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a _Layout.cshtml as the top level layout for the page (which includes a header and footer, ect.).  Then, I have a _MainLayout.cshtml which I want to contain two partial pages.  See code below.

To keep it simple for starters, all I want to do at this time is display the two partial pages (each containing simple text "Hello World").  Sounds simple, huh?  **NOT!**

## _MainLayout.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
}

<div>
    <div class="large-2 columns" style="min-height: 800px; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: lightgray; ">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/MenuPartial.cshtml");
    </div>
    <div class="large-10 columns" style="min-height: 800px; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: lightgray; ">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/ContentPartial.cshtml");
    </div> 
</div>
```

Do the partials in this layout need to be layouts themselves?  I've tried so many different things that I am completely confused and frustrated.

Eventually these will need to have controllers and a lot of JavaScript behind them.  But for now, all I want is to display two very simple partial views.

Comment: Which view have you shown us? (it makes no sense to have `Layout = ".._MainLayout.cshtml"` if you claiming `_Layout.cshtml` is you layout)

Comment: You are correct.  I screwed up.  The question has been updated.  I work on a locked down computer, so I cannot copy and paste from the actual code.  :-(

Comment: Its not clear what your trying to so. Are you wanting to create nested layouts? - if so [this article](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/164/nested-layout-pages-with-razor) my help

Comment: Well, I’m using nested layouts and that might be why I’m so confused.  Do these two references to the partial views need to be references to separate partial view layouts, because I’m referencing them from a layout?  I was able to get nested layouts working with sections but I’m really struggling with the partial views.  Eventually I’ll need some JavaScript to display 1 of 7 different menus on one partial view depending on user selection and what is displayed on the other partial view will depend on user selection from that menu in the other partial.

Comment: But for starters I just want to display two partial views with plain text.  That would make my day!

Comment: I’d be happy to use sections but I need controllers.  From my research, I can get controllers only by using views and partial views.

Comment: I do not understand you last comment (it does not really make sense). And is there a particular reason you want to use nested layouts?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - It may be best if I can load partial views inside a view without using nested layouts.  I'm stuck with the top level layout (_Layout.cshtml) but you might be onto something here if I can do this without using a layout for my two partial views.  If you're confused by what I am trying to do, it may be a reflection of just how confused I am.  Thank you for your helpful hints.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I upvoted your last comment, because it was very helpful.  Thank you for helping me out of my state of confusion.  You're AWESOME!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to show just two partial pages on start , then Get all this code into a controller action view. and not in a Layout.

Comment: There is a completely different view that is displayed on start.  My view is the content that gets displayed based on a user selection from a menu in the header.  Based on user selection the left partial view will contain 1 of 7 list options.   The right partial view will get populated from user selection in the left partial view.  Setting the elements for display requires controllers for both partial views.

Comment: After rethinking my implementation I realized your answer did work.  :-)

Comment: Ok... addition to the above comments..if left partial view is common view as layout for all pages that will be rendered in right panel....then your left view code must be in layout view itself. Hope make sense..